# Error Inflating layout customView

Tags: java, android, xml

I Have made a custom ImageView class for fade image. It works fine with the Android 5.0 and above as i tested. but i am getting an Inflating layout error when trying to run in API level 18 (Jelly Been 4.3).
i don't know why i am getting this error.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class global.buss.logics.FadeImageView
```

here is my class:

```
public class FadeImageView extends AppCompatImageView{
private FadeSide mFadeSide;
private Context c;

public enum FadeSide {
    RIGHT_SIDE, LEFT_SIDE, TOP_SIDE, BOTTOM_SIDE
}

public FadeImageView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(c, attrs, defStyle);
    this.c = c;
    init();
}

public FadeImageView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
    this.c = c;
    init();
}

public FadeImageView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    this.c = c;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // Enable horizontal/vertical fading
    this.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
    this.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
    // Apply default fading length
    this.setEdgeLength(14);
    // Apply default side
    this.setFadeDirection(FadeSide.TOP_SIDE);
}

public void setFadeDirection(FadeSide side) {
    this.mFadeSide = side;
}

public void setEdgeLength(int length) {
    this.setFadingEdgeLength(getPixels(length));
}

@Override
protected float getTopFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return mFadeSide.equals(FadeSide.TOP_SIDE) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return mFadeSide.equals(FadeSide.BOTTOM_SIDE) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

@Override
protected float getLeftFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return mFadeSide.equals(FadeSide.LEFT_SIDE) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

@Override
protected float getRightFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return mFadeSide.equals(FadeSide.RIGHT_SIDE) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

@Override
public boolean hasOverlappingRendering() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) {
    return false;
}

private int getPixels(int dipValue) {
    Resources r = c.getResources();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dipValue, r.getDisplayMetrics());
}}
```

and here's how i have implemented.

```
<global.buss.logics.FadeImageView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bg_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/mgnrega_vill"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

I have my package structure like this.

[image]

Any help will appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: add like this `<yourpkgname.FadeImageView`

Comment: Already Added with package name.

Comment: make your `global.buss.logics` inside come pkg

Comment: Does it matter?
But it works fine in the above api level.

Comment: @chandankumar have you tried changing AppCompatImageView to simple ImageVIew ?

Comment: yes, getting the same error with `ImageView` too.

Comment: @chandankumar is @drawable/mgnrega_vill a vector image or a .png file ?

Comment: its a .jpg file

Comment: it's wired this coding is working fine on my side.

Comment: in which device did you tried?

Comment: I 'm getting this issue in Sony Xperia M (C2004) which have Jelly been 4.3 (API level 18). Rather than it i tried on redmi note 3, Moto E3 Power, and some device of Lenovo, no issue at all it works fine.